# Question about a solution of a system of three non linear equations in three unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $$ a + \frac{1}{b} = 3$$  $$b + \frac{1}{c} = 4$$ $$ c + \frac{1}{a} = \frac{9}{11} $$ then $$ a \times b \times c  =?$$

I tried doing this problem but I was unsuccessful. Tried a lot but couldn't get the answer! The answer is a numerical value...

Comment: Come on, no need to close this immediately as "unclear what you're asking". Give the OP the time to correct it.

Comment: I am sorry. It has been edited now.

Comment: Could you give an outline of your approach? I'm not asking to include everything you've tried, but you may make it easier for 'us' if you show some possible approaches.

Comment: But sir, I guess it is not the same case here in this question. Here, it isn't $ x + 1/x$, here it is sort of $ x + 1/y = z $.

Comment: Okay, so basically there are 3 variables and 3 equations, so it is possible to find the value of a, b and c. However, I was unsuccessful in doing so. (I tried substituting)

Comment: Use the first two equations to express $a$ and $c$ in terms of $b$ and substitute in the last to give a quadratic for $b$.

Comment: Always try to show your question with your work. It's a type of home work so only hint would be given instead of answers. And that would urge you to do your question yourself and your skills will get better!

Comment: Yes, I agree. I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 12):

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that

\begin{align}
a + \frac{1}{b} &= 3 \tag{1}\label{1}
\\
b + \frac{1}{c} &= 4  \tag{2}\label{2}
\\
c + \frac{1}{a} &= \frac{9}{11} \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

\eqref{1}$\times$\eqref{2}$\times$\eqref{3}
$-$\eqref{1}$-$\eqref{2}$-$\eqref{3} gives:
\begin{align}
abc+\frac{1}{abc}&=2,
\end{align}

hence $abc=1$.

Comment: Very neatly done.

Comment: Thankyou! Appreciate it a lot...

Comment: While the deduction is in itself complete, I think an argument to show that a solution actually exists would be appropriate; if this were false then any other outcome could also be obtained.

Answer (score 8):

Eliminate $a$ and $c$:
$$a=3-\frac1b$$
$$c=\frac1{4-b}$$

Then

$$c+\frac1a=\frac1{4-b}+\frac b{3b-1}=\frac9{11},$$
can be rewritten
$$16b^2-40b+25=(4b-5)^2=0.$$
Hence
$$b=\frac54,a=\frac{11}5,c=\frac4{11}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way
we have :
$$b=\dfrac{1}{3-a}\ \ \  c=\dfrac{1}{4-b}\tag1$$
hence :
$$\dfrac{1}{4-\dfrac{1}{3-a}}+\frac{1}{a}=\frac{3-a}{11-4a}+\frac{1}{a}=\frac{9}{11}$$

so $11((3-a)a-11+4a)=9a(11-4a)$ or $25a^2-110a+121=0$ so $a=\frac{11}{5}$ and here you can find $a$ and repalce in $(1)$ to find $b$ and $c$